# How do I create very small shapes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I'd like to draw multiple very small shapes. But there seems to be a minimum size of approx. 3mm (for circles) if I use `minimum width` to change the size.

Is there a simple way to create smaller shapes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/4}
    \node[circle, draw,minimum width=\y mm, label={90:\y mm}] (c\x) at (\x,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `inner sep=0pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/4}
    \node[inner sep=0pt,circle, draw,minimum width=\y mm, label={90:\y mm}] (c\x) at (\x,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solved it!

Comment: @Zapnuk If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: I wanted to but there is a time contraint. I's only possible 15min after creating the post :)